# Using node style color in foreach loop messes the node label text up. Why and how to fix?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Trying to use `\foreach` for node placement and coloring fails. Node label becomes e.g. `redredcaptionA` where `red` is the desired color and `captionA` is the node label text.

Desired result would be a node with `captionA` as label text in red font color.

MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \i/\text/\color in {{1,1}/captionA/{red},{2,2}/captionB/{blue}}
        {\node[text=\color] at (\i) {\text};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have seen some related posts, where the node definition needs to be in an \edef definition but it's not solving the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be because you're (locally) redefining `\color`, use for example `\ccolor` as the loop variable instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \ii/\ttext/\ccolor in {{1,1}/captionA/{red},{2,2}/captionB/{blue}}
        {\node[text=\ccolor] at (\ii) {\ttext};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doh. Namespace...